# How do you get JavaFX ListView to be the height of its items?

Tags: javafx-2

If I create a ListView:

```
new ListView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("1", "2", "3"))
```

I would expect it to create a ListView with 3 rows. But it doesn't. It creates a ListView of 17 or so rows. Is there a way to tell ListView to always be the height such that whatever items are in it are always shown but no blank rows?

Having it auto width would also be useful, so it's always as wide as the widest row.

One purpose of this is that then it could be used in a ScrollPane. I know it has its own scrollbars, but they don't offer sufficient control.

Comment: You can use [css so that additional blank rows in a ListView are not visible](http://fxexperience.com/2011/11/alternate-row-highlighting-in-empty-tableview-and-listview-rows/).  It is not quite the same as sizing the ListView itself to the height of its items, but perhaps it is sufficient for you.

Comment: @jewelsea I saw examples of that, but that's not what I need.

Comment: For your requirements, I suggest using a [VBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html) in a [ScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html) instead of a `ListView`.

Comment: I've seen examples of that, too. It's a little frustrating that the first solution to ListView issues is to dump it and roll your own.

Comment: taotree - in future I advise summarizing in your question the results of prior research you have done on the problem space.

Answer (score 13):

I just found out that Paul Marshall's answer can be reducted to a one-liner using [Bindings.size](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#size%28javafx.collections.ObservableList%29) that creates a numeric jfx property representing the size of an ObservableList :

```
listView.prefHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.size(itemListProperty).multiply(LIST_CELL_HEIGHT));
```

The list cell height must sadly still be hardcoded AFAIK.

Comment: What is itemListProperty?

Comment: figured it out. Although I had to use maxHeightProperty

Comment: Could you explain what you have figured out ?

Comment: Only works for fixed cell height (if a cell has a different height from another cell in the list, that solution wouldn't work).

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately there is not a nice, clean size Property of an ObservableList for us to bind to.  Instead, it's doable by adding a ListChangeListener on the list, at least, that's how I've done it in the past.  By default the size of each row should be 24px, and we need an extra pixel on the top and bottom for the ListView's edges.  Otherwise we still have the ListView's scroll bar showing.  First we'll create the ObservableList and the ListView, and set the initial height of the ListView:

```
/*
 * Each row in a ListView should be 24px tall.  Also, we have to add an extra
 * two px to account for the borders of the ListView.
 */
final int ROW_HEIGHT = 24;
final ObservableList items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("1", "2", "3");
final ListView list = new ListView(items);

// This sets the initial height of the ListView:
list.setPrefHeight(items().size() * ROW_HEIGHT + 2);
```

Now we have to add a ListChangeListener to the ObservableList.  When the list changes, we simply change the set height of the ListView to match the new number of rows.  If we know that we are never going to add or remove items from the ObservableList that is backing the ListView, then we can exclude the listener.  Again, the height is the number of rows times the height per row plus two extra pixels for the borders:

```
/*
 * This listener will resize the ListView when items are added or removed
 * from the ObservableList that is backing the ListView:
 */
items.addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChanger(ListChangeListener.Change change) {
        list.setPrefHeight(items.size() * ROW_HEIGHT + 2);
    }
});
```

References:
[JavaFX ListView Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html), [JavaFX ObservableList Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html)

Comment: Hardcoding the row height at 24 is unacceptable, and the assumption about the border is unreliable, also. Figuring out row height, border width, etc., somehow from styling or tricky stuff is messy, but probably the only way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Why not `list.lookup(".list-cell").getHeight()`? this allows you to set size in css.

Answer (score 5):

Are you searching for that:

```
.list-cell:empty {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}
```

This will hide empty cell's.

Answer (score 3):

I found a relatively easy though still slightly hacky solution which works under the assumption that all non-empty cells have the same height: instead of parsing css or some such, add an `InvalidationListener` to your `listView.getItems()`; the first time your items list becomes non-empty, you recursively go through the `ListView`s children until you find an instance of `ListCell` where `!cell.isEmpty()`, and store the value of `cell.getHeight()`. Be sure to wrap that code in a `Platform.runLater()` so that it gets executed once the `ListView` layouting is done. Once you have that height, you multiply it with `listView.getItems().size()` and call `listView.setMaxHeight` with the resulting value (still inside the `InvalidationListener`).

Comment: Actually don't use recursion, just `lookup(".list-cell")` and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflow's reputation system is preventing me from commenting on Paul Marshall's answer, but I wanted to add for anyone else looking at this that his 24px estimate for rows is "generally" confirmed by the official JavaFX documentation - see "fixedCellSize" at http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html:

> Generally cells are around 24px...

So while I agree that "[f]iguring out row height, border width, etc., somehow from styling or tricky stuff is messy, but probably the only way to do it" may be true, starting with an assumption that is backed up by official documentation is a good place to start, and seems to result in decent-looking lists in my testing on a ListView (using Java 7).

Comment: That size can be set directly, modified by stylesheets, different based on look and feel, platform (android?), etc. so regardless if a default even exists, it's not something to be counted on.

Comment: That's true for anything that has defaults that can be modified ever, and doesn't remove the utility of knowing what the default was in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

After working hard and based in the @warakawa answer, I found the solution. As we all know, the implementation of the Listview is causing many headaches, because of this I wrote two classes that fixes the problem of "PREF_SIZE" (which has a constant of 400 for the height and width is calculated according to height). The skin class that I wrote calculates the size as we expect and also prevents ugly horizontal bar when the new property "fillWidth" is changed to "true", this property causes the cells to grow horizontally as much as possible. Regards.

**ListViewFixed.java**

```
package javafxapplication;

import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;

public class ListViewFixed<T> extends javafx.scene.control.ListView<T>
{
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Properties">
    private final BooleanProperty fillWidth = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "fillWidth");

    public final BooleanProperty fillWidthProperty()
    {
        return fillWidth;
    }

    public final boolean isFillWidth()
    {
        return fillWidth.get();
    }

    public final void setFillWidth(boolean fillWidth)
    {
        this.fillWidth.set(fillWidth);
    }
    // </editor-fold>

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Methods">
    @Override
    protected Skin createDefaultSkin()
    {
        return new ListViewFixedSkin(this);
    }
    // </editor-fold>
}
```

**ListViewFixedSkin.java**

```
package javafxapplication;

import java.util.Set;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;

public class ListViewFixedSkin extends com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ListViewSkin
{
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Fields">
    private ListViewFixed listView;
    private ScrollBar scrollBarHorizontal;
    private ScrollBar scrollBarVertical;
    private boolean fillWidthCache;
    private double prefWidthCache;
    private Region placeholderRegion;
    // </editor-fold>

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Constructors">
    public ListViewFixedSkin(ListViewFixed listView)
    {
        super(listView);

        this.listView = listView;

        registerChangeListener(listView.fillWidthProperty(), "FILL_WIDTH");
    }
    // </editor-fold>

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Methods">
    private void updateFillWidth()
    {
        if (scrollBarHorizontal != null && scrollBarVertical != null && fillWidthCache != listView.isFillWidth())
        {
            if (listView.isFillWidth() && !fillWidthCache)
            {
                scrollBarHorizontal.visibleProperty().addListener(this::updateCellsPrefWidth);
                scrollBarVertical.visibleProperty().addListener(this::updateCellsPrefWidth);
            }
            else
            {
                scrollBarHorizontal.visibleProperty().removeListener(this::updateCellsPrefWidth);
                scrollBarVertical.visibleProperty().removeListener(this::updateCellsPrefWidth);
            }

            fillWidthCache = listView.isFillWidth();
        }
    }

    private void updateCellsPrefWidth(Observable o)
    {
        final Insets insets = getSkinnable().getInsets();
        final double prefWidth = getSkinnable().getWidth() + insets.getLeft() + insets.getRight() - scrollBarVertical.getWidth();

        if (prefWidth != prefWidthCache)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < flow.getCellCount(); i++)
            {
                final IndexedCell cell = flow.getCell(i);

                if (!cell.isEmpty())
                {
                    cell.setPrefWidth(prefWidth);
                }
            }

            prefWidthCache = prefWidth;
        }
    }

    private boolean showingPlaceHolder()
    {
        checkState();

        if (getItemCount() == 0)
        {
            if (placeholderRegion == null)
            {
                updatePlaceholderRegionVisibility();

                final Object obj = getChildren().get(getChildren().size() - 1);
                if (obj instanceof Node && ((Region) obj).getStyleClass().contains("placeholder"))
                {
                    placeholderRegion = (Region) obj;
                }
            }

            if (placeholderRegion != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleControlPropertyChanged(String p)
    {
        super.handleControlPropertyChanged(p);
        if ("FILL_WIDTH".equals(p))
        {
            updateFillWidth();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefHeight(double width, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset)
    {
        if (showingPlaceHolder())
        {
            return super.computePrefHeight(width, topInset, rightInset, bottomInset, leftInset);
        }
        else
        {
            double computedHeight = topInset + bottomInset;

            for (int i = 0; i < flow.getCellCount(); i++)
            {
                final IndexedCell cell = flow.getCell(i);

                if (!cell.isEmpty())
                {
                    computedHeight += cell.getHeight();
                }
            }

            return computedHeight;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefWidth(double height, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset)
    {
        double computedWidth = 0;

        if (showingPlaceHolder())
        {
            computedWidth += placeholderRegion.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < flow.getCellCount(); i++)
            {
                final IndexedCell cell = flow.getCell(i);

                if (!cell.isEmpty() && cell.getWidth() > computedWidth)
                {
                    computedWidth = cell.getWidth();
                }
            }

            if (scrollBarVertical != null && scrollBarVertical.isVisible())
            {
                computedWidth += scrollBarVertical.getWidth();
            }
        }

        if (computedWidth != 0)
        {
            return computedWidth + leftInset + rightInset;
        }
        else
        {
            return super.computePrefWidth(height, topInset, rightInset, bottomInset, leftInset);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren(double x, double y, double w, double h)
    {
        super.layoutChildren(x, y, w, h);

        if (scrollBarHorizontal == null || scrollBarVertical == null)
        {
            final Set<Node> nodes = getSkinnable().lookupAll(".scroll-bar");

            nodes.stream().forEach((node) ->
            {
                if (node instanceof ScrollBar)
                {
                    final ScrollBar scrollBar = (ScrollBar) node;

                    if (scrollBar.getOrientation() == Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
                    {
                        scrollBarHorizontal = scrollBar;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        scrollBarVertical = scrollBar;
                    }
                }
            });

            updateFillWidth();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose()
    {
        if (fillWidthCache)
        {
            scrollBarHorizontal.visibleProperty().removeListener(this::updateCellsPrefWidth);
            scrollBarVertical.visibleProperty().removeListener(this::updateCellsPrefWidth);
        }

        listView = null;

        super.dispose();
    }
    // </editor-fold>
}
```

**WARNING**
There are some fixes to do at ListViewFixedSkin.java class. Where i pass methods by reference directly it should be stored before in an variable and then you pass the variable in add/attachments/remove/detachments methods. Otherwise this can cause memory problems.

Comment: How would you use this in your application? (especially with scene builder)

Comment: You will use as any other custom component. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to force the JavaFX Thread to finish drawing the items in the ListView before being able to calculate the height of the cell.

```
public void loadItems(ObservableList<String> items) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        listView.setItems(items);
        listView.layout();
        listView.applyCss();
                
        double cellHeight = ((LabelCell) listView.lookup(".list-cell")).getHeight();
        double items = listView.getItems().size();
        listView.setPrefHeight(cellHeight * items);
    });
} // loadItems
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to setPrefHeight(double) in subclass of ListCell. For example in my code

```
@Override
public void updateItem(File item, boolean empty)
{
  super.updateItem(item, empty);
  if (empty) {
    setText(null);
    setGraphic(null);
  } else {
    setText(item.getName());
    setGraphic(null);
    setPrefHeight(getSize(item)/getsize(folder));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Example Image to set ListView Height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdUzs.jpg)

If you have a static list , You can set the list view height with the setter method that comes with the ListView class setPrefHeight

```
ListView.setPrefHeight(140);
```

Answer (score 0):

I based my answer on the answers provided by @scribbleslims and @Alexandre Mazari

`listView.setPrefHeight(listView.getItems().size() * LIST_CELL_HEIGHT);`

You have to define `LIST_CELL_HEIGHT` on your own.

In my case, I used 29.501.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @tonimaroni answer... I found this worked.

```
.list-view {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.list-cell:empty {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).